# 2 Simultaneous type renamings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, tuples, simultaneous, renaming

we've been given the task to make a Dictionary, as a List of tuples with (String, String).
The problem here is that I actually have no idea if I can rename String twice at the same time, since I want the tuple to look like this

```
(German, English)
```

Is it even possible to just make it look like this?

```
type German =  String
type English = String
type Dictionary = [(German, English)]
```

Or would there be any conflicts?
It was kinda frustrating not finding a single entry about this, been almost 2 hours and not a single line of code stands right now :|

Comment: Well, you know, Haskell won't exactly punish you for trying things out. In addition, the Haskell 2010 Report should have all documentation needed to understand type aliases. Of course, there may not be an answer for every question, as well as it is probably nowhere explicitly stated that you may bind two variables to 42.

Comment: I have voted to close this question, perhaps controversially. My rationale is like this: I couldn't identify a problem to solve in the question body. (The closest thing is essentially "I am afraid this won't work". But fear isn't a problem we can solve for you.) Because there is no problem to solve, there can't be a solution -- and that means this is not a helpful thing to have on the site. The question could be significantly improved by including an input/output pair that does not match your expectations -- e.g. a compilation error, or a program to run together with the behavior you expected.

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree with your reasoning.  The question essentially boils down to "will this work?" without demonstrating that it was attempted beforehand.  While this is a somewhat unconventional question, that does certainly fall within the definition of an improper question.  I have voted to close many posts where the asker had not attempted a solution, but usually it was out of laziness or not knowing where to start instead of fear.

Comment: I may have to agree with you here. I was kinda afraid because while Haskell itself may not be very punishing, Hugs sure is, and it's basically what I have to use in my University course. After the question was answered I immediately continued, so there wouldn't be a problem at all with closing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can't do the opposite

```
type German = String
type German = Int        -- conflicts here!
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, if you couldn't, you wouldn't be able to compile `type German = String` in the first place, as it's already been named ;-)